# MySQL, Inserting multiple row from string separated by comma

Tags: mysql

I understand that I can use the value in `insert into` to insert multiple rows by columns but my case is a bit different:

I have a string that looks like this: "2,5,14,25,30".

And a connection table that has 2 columns: (INT UserId, INT GroupId).

Let's say I want to connect userId = 1 with all the IDs in the string, how should I do that?

I am familiar with the `FIND_IN_SET()` function that helps me search for those IDs, but I can't figure how to use it in this case.

In the end, I want my table to look like this:

```
UserId | GroupId
-----------------
   1   |   2
   1   |   5
   1   |   14
   1   |   25
   1   |   30
```

Comment: You could use a prepared statement, I guess.

Comment: I guess so... wanted to see if there is a better practice for this

Comment: Do you have a table that contains all possible group ids (with one groupid per row)?

Comment: yes of course. I have a users table with UserId as primary key, and groups table with GroupId as primary key.